# $S$ subring of $R$ implies $\mathrm{rank}_R M\leq \mathrm{rank}_S M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, free-modules

Update: I posted the question with the WRONG inequality!! (Now it's ok)

I have a problem with the following statement:

True or False: Let $S$ be a subring of $R$ (unitary but not necessarily commutative), $M$ a $\textbf{free}$ $R$-module and suppose that $\mathrm{rank}_R M, \mathrm{rank}_S M$ both exist, then $\mathrm{rank}_R M\leq \mathrm{rank}_S M$.

I think it's true (but maybe is false). My thoughts: $R$ is a $S$-module with $s\cdot r=sr$, so if $\mathrm{rank}_R M=r$ and $\mathrm{rank}_S M=s$ then $M\cong \bigoplus_r R$ (isomorphism of $R$-modules) and $M\cong \bigoplus_s S$ (isomorphism of $S$-modules). Moreover, we know that the inclusion $\iota:R\to S$ induces an injective $S$-module homomorphism $\bigoplus_r S\to \bigoplus_r R$ and $\bigoplus_s S\to \bigoplus_s R$ but I cannot relate these things.

Can anyone provide me some hints? Thank you!

Comment: If $R$ is commutative, then the property holds since an $R$-basis of $M$ is linearly independent over $S$, so there is an injection $S^r\to M$, and therefore  $\mathrm{rank}_S(M)\ge r$ (not a trivial result!).

Comment: Yes, if $R$ is commutative, following the steps of the deleted answer and using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476967/basis-of-finitely-generated-free-r-module I can prove it (I think). I don't know if $R$ is not commutative. In that question, someone says "Over non commutative ring, the notion of rank is not well defined for finitely generated free modules: there are non commutative rings $R$ such that, as $R$-modules, $R\cong R\oplus R$. But in this case $\mathrm{rank}_R M, \mathrm{rank}_ M$ are well-defined.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352956/s-subring-of-r-implies-mathrmrank-r-m-leq-mathrmrank-s-m

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a field and let $R = S \oplus S$, $M = S \oplus S \oplus S \oplus S$. Then $S \leq R$ and $\operatorname{rank}_S(M) = 4$, but $\operatorname{rank}_R(M) = 2$.

Comment: Sorry, I've posted the question with the wrong inequality, Now I've edited. Anyway, your answer is useful